# How to render about-us component in the footer section which is linked to constants folder in nextJs app

Tags: next.js13

This is my constants folder with a file named index.js
`export const footerLinks = [
{
title: "About",
links: [
{title: "About Us", url: "/about"},

```
],
},
{
title: "Service",
links: [
{title: "Events", url: "/"},
{title: "Blog", url: "/"},
{title: "Services", url: "/"},
  
],
},
{
title: "Socials",
links: [
{ title: "WhatsApp", url: "/" },
{ title: "Facebook", url: "/" },
{ title: "LinkedIn", url: "/" },
{ title: "Twitter", url: "/" },
],
},
];
```

I want to create About.tsx file with some content so that anytime I click on the about url in my footer, it will render the About.tsx file.

This is also my Footer.tsx file

```
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";

import { footerLinks } from "@constants";
const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
const Footer = () => (

<footer className='flex flex-col text-black-100  mt-5                     border-t border-gray-100'>
<div className='flex max-md:flex-col flex-wrap justify-between gap-5 sm:px-16 px-6 py-10'>
  <div className='flex flex-col justify-start items-start gap-6'>
    <Image src='/logos.svg' alt='logo' width={118} height={18} className='object-contain' />
    <p className='text-base text-gray-700'>
       { currentYear}<br />
      All Rights Reserved &copy;
    </p>
  </div>

  <div className="footer__links">
    {footerLinks.map((item) => (
      <div key={item.title} className="footer__link">
        <h3 className="font-bold">{item.title}</h3>
        {/* <div className="flex flex-col gap-5"> */}
          {item.links.map((link) => (
            <Link
              target="_blank"
              key={link.title}
              href={link.url}
              className="text-gray-500"
            >
              {link.title}
            </Link>
          ))}
        {/* </div> */}
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
</div>

<div className='flex justify-between items-center flex-         wrap mt-10 border-t border-gray-100 sm:px-16 px-6 py-10'>
  <p>@{currentYear} O All rights reserved</p>
     <div className="footer__copyrights-link">
    <Link href="/" className="text-gray-500">
      Privacy & Policy
    </Link>
<Link href="/" className="text-gray-500">
Terms & Condition
</Link>
</div>
</div>
</footer>
);
export default Footer;`
```

I have created the About.tsx file but still not rendering